# Timer rollover handling

Tags: c, timer, embedded, real-time, atomic

I have a 32 bit hardware timer that I'd like to extend to 64 bit effective length in software.

In my embedded system, I have available a 32-bit hardware "core timer" (CT) that ticks at ~ 40 MHz, so it rolls over in about 107 seconds.

That's great for precise timing of periods up to 107 seconds. But I'd like to do equally precise timing of longer periods.

It also has a 32-bit "period" register - when the CT value matches the period register, an interrupt is generated.

My ISR looks like this (simplified for clarity):

```
const UINT32 ONE_MILLISECOND = TICK_RATE/1000;

UINT64 SwRTC;

void CT_ISR(void) {
    PeriodRegister += ONE_MILLISECOND;
    SwRTC += ONE_MILLISECOND;
    ClearCTInterrupt();
}
```

So, now I have a 64 bit "SwRTC" that can be used to measure longer periods, but only to a precision of 1 millisecond, plus the 32-bit hardware timer that is precise to 1/40 MHz (25 nanoseconds). Both use the same units (TICK_RATE).

How can I combine both to get a 64 bit timer that's equally precise, while still getting interrupts at 1000 Hz?

My first try looked like this:

```
UINT64 RTC(void){

    UINT64 result;

    DisableInterrupts(); // to allow atomic operations

    result = (SwRTC & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ull) + ReadCoreTimer();

    EnableInterrupts();

    return result;
}
```

But that's no good, because if the CT rolls over while interrupts are disabled then I'll get a result with a small number in the low-order 32 bits, but without the high-order bits having been incremented by the ISR.

Maybe something like this would work - read it twice and return the higher value:

```
UINT64 RTC(void){

    UINT64 result1, result2;

    DisableInterrupts(); // to allow atomic operations

    result1 = (SwRTC & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ull) + ReadCoreTimer();

    EnableInterrupts();

    DisableInterrupts(); // again

    result2 = (SwRTC & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ull) + ReadCoreTimer();

    EnableInterrupts();

    if (result1 > result2)
        return result1;
     else
        return result2;
}
```

I'm not sure if that'll work or if there is a hidden problem there I've missed.

What is the best way to do this?

(Some may ask why I need to time such long periods so precisely in the first place. It's mainly for simplicity - I don't want to use 2 different timing methods depending on the period; I'd prefer to use the same method all the time.)

Comment: What is TICK_RATE?
Why are you not just incrementing another 32 bit counter every time there is a rollover and then using the two combined fields to calculate the elapsed time.

Comment: TICK_RATE is the rate at which the hardware timer ticks (ticks/second). I don't get an interrupt when the 32 bit timer rolls over, so I can't do that. (Because I'm using the period register to generate 1 kHz interrupts instead.)

Comment: Alright what hardware are you using then?

Comment: "I don't want to use 2 different timing methods depending on the period; I'd prefer to use the same method all the time." The best advice anyone can give you is, "Don't do that." Standard practice is to use the hardware counter for timing up to 1 second, and use the millisecond counter for timing over 1 second.  The second line of the interrupt routine should be `SwRTC++;` so that `SwRTC` just counts milliseconds.

Comment: Also what resolution do you actually need since resolution of 25 nanoseconds doesn't make any sense in the present context. [Because your current software configuration (nor any that I know of) can't make use of that resolution]

Comment: @Treesrule14: It's a PIC32MX, not that I see how it matters. It's not a matter of how much resolution I need - it's that I don't want 2 different timing mechanisms.

Comment: @user3386109: If I did that, then SwRTC would count in units of milliseconds, while ReadCoreTimer() would still be counting in units of 25 nS. That means I'd need two different values of ONE_SECOND (for instance) - one for each timer.  That's "asking for trouble".

Comment: "That's asking for trouble." Yes it is, you shouldn't have a define for ONE_SECOND anywhere in your code. Instead, use functions to hide the messy details, e.g. `ssleep(int seconds)`, `msleep(int milliseconds)`, and `usleep(int microseconds)`.  Likewise for getting start times and computing time deltas.

Comment: @user336109: What if I want to do something 5 seconds in the future?  Or measure the time between 2 events?  Seems like there's a lot of occasion for constants like ONE_SECOND.

Comment: `int start = stime();  /*time passes*/ if ( sdelta(start) > 5) dosomething;` to do something 5 seconds from now (assuming that you aren't using an RTOS that has scheduling mechanisms, but are just periodically polling to see if it's time to do something.) `int start = utime();  /*time passes*/ int delta = udelta( start );` to measure the time between two events with microsecond precision.

Comment: One thing doesn't make sense to me (if I got it right). It appears that in line `SwRTC += ONE_MILLISECOND;`, `ONE_MILLISECOND` is not `2<<32`. Can you specify the exact value of `TICK_RATE`? Because the only way for this to work correctly would be to increase `SwRTC` by `2<<32` whenever `ReadCoreTimer()` overflows, and I don't think that's happening. In other words, `x % 100` is not the same as `x & 0xFF00`.

Comment: @nerdfever.com it matters because I wanted to know what resources you had available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've *almost* solved this myself:

```
UINT64 Rtc(void){

    UINT64 softwareTimer = SwRTC;
    UINT32 lowOrderBits = softwareTimer;                        // just take low-order 32 bits
    UINT64 coreTimer = ReadCoreTimer();

    if (lowOrderBits > coreTimer)                               // if CT has rolled over since SwRTC was updated
        softwareTimer += 0x100000000;                           // then increment high-order 32 bits of software count

    return (softwareTimer & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ull) + coreTimer; 
}
```

This first reads the 64-bit software timer, then the 32-bit hardware timer.

The hardware timer (updated every 25 nS) should always be >= the low-order 32-bits of the software timer (updated only every 1 mS).

If it's not, that indicates the hardware timer rolled over since the software timer was read.

So, in that case I increment the high-order word of the software timer.

Then just combine the high-order 32 bits from the software time with the low-order 32 bits from the hardware timer.

One nice side effect is there's no need to disable interrupts.

The only problem I can see is, what if compiler optimization re-orders the code so that the hardware timer gets read first? Then I could get an interrupt that increments the software timer before I have a chance to read it.

At first I thought I could fix that by disabling interrupts while reading both timers, but what if the compiler re-orders the code so the DisableInterrupts() comes too late?

Comment: Apart from the comment for the question, reordering of instructions is not the only problem here. What will happen if `CT_ISR` interrupt routine gets called between reads to `SwRTC` and `ReadCoreTimer()`?

Comment: @Groo: I don't think that's a problem. If CT_ISR() gets called between the two reads, it will affect the high-order 32 bits of SwRTC (which is all I'm using here) only if the hardware CT rolled over recently (in the last millisecond). That will be detected by the if() statement, which will increment "softwareTimer" to compensate for that. (That's why I use a stored copy of SwRTC in softwareTimer in the comparison and return statement, instead of SwRTC).) So I think that's OK. Unless I messed up... [I'm still worried about the instruction reordering tho.]

Comment: Answering my own question re re-ordering of instructions: If both the hardware timer and the software timer are declared "volatile" (as they should be), the compiler won't reorder access to them.

Comment: One potential issue with this solution on a preemptive OS:the thread running rtc() could get swapped out for the entire period of the timer(107 seconds, unlikely, but if you had a very high resolution timer with 1ns or 0.1 ns tick it is more possible), you could miss a rollover. To fix this, you would need to disable preemption when this function is called, to ensure that the logic works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an upcounter for example I will typically

```
elapsed = ((nowtime-starttime)&MASK)+(rollovers<<SIZE);
```

so long as you sample often enough (many times per rollover) for an upcounter of nowtime (time I just sampled) is less than lasttime (lasttime is the prior nowtime) then it rolled over.

assuming it is counting out every value and not skipping from say 0xFF..FFF to 0x00...01.

Downcounter just do everything opposite starttime-nowtime.  nowtime > lasttime.

Some timers have a rollover interrupt which you can sometimes just poll instead of interrupt if you want and again so long as you can guarantee you sample that once or more than once per rollover you can simply use that to flag a rollover count.

If at any time you miss a rollover, then naturally you will be off by the size of the timer 4 giga counts or whatever.

Some hardware may allow for you to use one timer to generate an output clock which you can then feedback as an input to another timer and cascade that way (sometimes they do that on chip).